# How to set custom title view to center of navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add custom view (Label) as title view of navigation item.

but it is not appearing in centre

```
func setupNavigationMultilineTitle(title:String) {
        let autoscrollLabel = EFAutoScrollLabel()
        autoscrollLabel.text =  title
        autoscrollLabel.textAlignment = .center
        autoscrollLabel.backgroundColor = .red

        autoscrollLabel.font = AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .Medium, size: 15)
        autoscrollLabel.textColor = AppTheme.Colors.ColorsOfApp.header_color.color
        autoscrollLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width ?? 0) - (self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.frame.width ?? 0) * 2) , height: 40)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = autoscrollLabel

    }
```

I have tried to use deduct width of custom view to show it in center but unfortunately it is not working.

I have also tried to get `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.width` but it returns 0. I confirmed that there is leftBarbutton item with  `po self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`

**EDIT**

This solves issue

```
    autoscrollLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 125, y: 0, width: 250 , height: 40)
```

But I need dynamic solution

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have subclassed UILabel ?

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi Yes it  is  third party library. But it is subclass of UILabel

Comment: By default title view is in center.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have to set frame to the label. Without setting frame I am not able to see the label.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I debugged your scenario, hope it helps you and other developers,

When we assign tittleView width by calculating the space left after subtracting space of items, margins, padding etc then iOS calculate titleView X from the right side i.e. `titleview.x = rightItem.x - width` and we are expecting it like `titleview.x = navbar.width/2 - width/2`.

Please look below sample test cases.

---

Calculate width

```
let maxItemOnEitherSide = max(arrLeftItems.count, arrRightItems.count)
let widthOfItem : CGFloat = 30.0
let pading : CGFloat = 40

let aWidth : CGFloat = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)! - CGFloat(maxItemOnEitherSide) * widthOfItem * 2.0 - pading

let lblNavTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                        width: aWidth,
                                        height: 40))
```

**Case 1 :** arrLeftItems.count = 1 and arrRightItems.count = 0.

Output :

[image]

**Case 2 :** arrLeftItems.count = 0 and arrRightItems.count = 1.

[image]

---

Hope above cases clear you out what we are expecting and what we are getting and the calculation that I wrote in first para i.e. `titleview.x = rightItem.x - width`.

**Conclusion :**

If rightBarItems have more items than leftBarItems then titleview will be in center, so you wont need to do anything but if leftBarItems have more items than rightBarItems then add blank items in right side to make it balance. It is weird for developers but seems like its the only solution.

Check the final output.

- View Heirarchy

[image]

- Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you efforts but why you have taken static value for `widthOfItem` and `pading`

Comment: `widthOfItem` is the width of my particular item, I done this in live project so I cant reveal all code, Here I have 4 items and every item have 30 width (to check your scenario im using one ) .BTW pading is for the space before the first navbarItem. in short leading space of item. Dont know how to calculate dynamically. Items frame origin is always zero. so for dummy I took padding as 40.

Comment: I am afraid to use padding value  because if  future version of iOS that might break.

Comment: I think this is `CGRect(x: self.view.center.x - 100, y: 0, width: 100 , height: 40)` more safer side to go and upvote for your efforts

Comment: you have give margin values, I dont think it will be break otherwise baritems will sticks to the left most side of the screen. Im using `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100 , height: 40)` , no need to calculate x, still working fine. I posted this answer but seems like your already done it so I deleted my previous answer.

Comment: Can someone make 40 more dynamic :) Great answer btw.

Comment: @EmreÖnder you can customise it anyway you want.

Comment: But I don't wanna hardcore variable. I tried to get back button size but couldn't get size.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation Item is part of a UINavigationController you could try
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.width ?? 0.0`

Comment: No it is still 0

Answer (score 0):

Add my version code based on @dahiya_boy answers.
In my case, I have a custom button that has a more 30-width size. So, rather than multiply it by 30, I find a max from left and right items to find the max.
Below is the code:

```
func setCenterTitle(_ title: String) {
        let navWidth = (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width).orZero
        let leftItemsWidth = leftBarButtonItems.orEmptyArray.reduce(0) {
            $0 + ($1.customView?.frame.width).orZero
        }
        let rightItemsWidth = rightBarButtonItems.orEmptyArray.reduce(0) {
            $0 + ($1.customView?.frame.width).orZero
        }
        let maxItemsWidth = max(leftItemsWidth, rightItemsWidth)
        let padding: CGFloat = 40
        let labelWidth = navWidth - (maxItemsWidth * 2) - padding
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: labelWidth, height: 40))
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        self.titleView = titleLabel
    }
```